# Does DTLS CertificateVerify consider fragmentation of packets when signing the handshake messages?

Tags: tls, certificates

For DTLS with client authentication, the client is required to send a CertificateVerify message, which has the following structure:

```
struct {
           digitally-signed struct {
               opaque handshake_messages[handshake_messages_length];
           }
      } CertificateVerify;
```

According to DTLS specification ([RFC 6347 - Section 4.2.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6347#section-4.2.6)), Finished messages (which also involve taking hash of the concatenation of all handshake messages) does not consider fragmentation of packets:

> CertificateVerify and Finished messages have the same format as in
> TLS.  Hash calculations include entire handshake messages, including
> DTLS-specific fields: message_seq, fragment_offset, and
> fragment_length.  **However, in order to remove sensitivity to handshake
> message fragmentation, the Finished MAC MUST be computed as if each
> handshake message had been sent as a single fragment.**

Is this the case for CertificateVerify as well, that is, does CertificateVerify sign the concatenation of handshake messages considering each message as a single fragment? If not, then is there any specific reason for keeping the two computations different? Implementations should become simpler (lesser storage requirements) if they are the same.